# I downloaded a github project but npm start doesn't work React

Tags: reactjs

I have downloaded this project from github.
https://github.com/john-smilga/react-projects/tree/master/01-birthday-reminder

but when opening it with visual studio code the following message appears to me:

```
PS C:\Users\Sistemas\Downloads\react-projects-master (1)\react-projects-master\01-birthday-reminder> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Sistemas\Downloads\react-projects-master 
(1)\react-projects-master\01-birthday-reminder/package.json     
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Sistemas\Downloads\react-projects-master (1)\react-projects-master\01-birthday-reminder\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a 
file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sistemas\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-04T17_54_32_986Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Sistemas\Downloads\react-projects-master (1)\react-projects-master\01-birthday-reminder>
```

Answer (score 0):

This because there is no package.json file on that path, launch the command in the [setup](https://github.com/john-smilga/react-projects/tree/master/01-birthday-reminder/setup) directory. Path on your machine could be **C:\Users\Sistemas\Downloads\react-projects-master (1)\react-projects-master\01-birthday-reminder\setup**

Comment: I have a question for you. All repositories downloaded from github need to be installed with npm install in the setup folder?

Comment: It is an wrong way of thinking as there are many github projects with different setup, programming language and way more configuration that do not (or could not) require npm but other tools. The setup folder is just a directory that you found in this project.